# How to keep javascript setTimeout running when user minimizes the browser on mobile

Tags: javascript, ios, vue.js, browser, web-worker

I have a countdown timer on my website. I ran into an issue where if the user switches tabs for too long the timer becomes out of sync with real time.

I fixed this issue by running the timer in a web worker. However, now I have noticed that on mobile devices such as iOS, users can minimize the browser which will still cause the timer to go out of sync. How should I fix this issue?

The timer also runs in the backend so I can refresh the tab to get the current time left.

Should I trigger the webpage reload when the tab refocuses?

Comment: It's common for mobile devices to pause execution of apps/tabs that are not active to save resources.  instead of setTimeout, calculating time with `new Date.now()` would be much more accurate and correct any drift caused from paused execution once the code is active again.